# Dataflow job stops processing messages after initial load in pubsub to pubsub streaming

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

In my setup I have an input subscription messages will be pushed to which is  read by a dataflow job. These messages are transformed to one or multiple output messages and then either published to a topic an error topic depending on success of the transformation. Both output topics live in a different project.

My code is as follows:

```
PCollectionTuple transformationOutput = p
            .apply("ReadMessageFromInputTopic", PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscriptionPath()))
            .apply("CreatePubsubMessageWindow", Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
            .apply("TransformMessageToGazelleInput", new Processor());

    transformationOutput.get(PipelineTags.MESSAGE)
            .apply("WriteMessageToSalesCategoryTopic", PubsubIO.writeMessages().to(options.getOutputTopicPath()));
    transformationOutput.get(PipelineTags.ERROR)
            .apply("WriteErrorToErrorTopic", PubsubIO.writeMessages().to(options.getErrorTopicPath()));
    p.run();
```

When I submit this code to dataflow (--runner=DataflowRunner), it will run for a while and then stop, while there are still messages that are unacknowledged according to the pubsub stackdriver metrics. The messages seem to be read from the subscription when checked with gcloud. Whenever I update (resubmit with --update) the job it will again process some messages.

Something I also noticed in the gcp ui for the job is that the system lag is high (multiple days) which in my understanding means that there is are old messages which are not being processed.

My guess is that I'm doing something wrong with the windowing function as this is the most confusing part to me. I'm wondering how to determine what kind of windowing function to use. The amount of messages on this subscription vary 0 for longer periods of time to a handfull of messages per seconds for a couple of hours.

Any help is appreciated :).

Comment: Can you explain what the `Processor` transform does? Does it do an aggregation on the windowed data? You may not need any windowing functionality.

Comment: The transform transforms a single message in multiple output messages (with the tuple tag MESSAGE). If some transformation exception occurs in this transformation it will instead transform it into a single error message (with the tuple tag ERROR). No aggregation is done.

Comment: If no aggregation transform is applied, you don't need the window transform. Try removing it and see what happens.

Comment: I have tried it without, but that gave the same results unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Marius -  Could you confirm whether you are seeing any messages successfully published to your output topics?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that I see messages published on both output topics

Comment: Right now I can't reproduce the problem anymore, I've emptied the messages that were unacknowledged on the subscription by redeploying multiple times until that queue was empty. It seems that the issue doesn't occur anymore now. Maybe it has something to do with a lot of messages being backed up?

Comment: Looks like it has something with the messages being backed up. However, you can report the issue at https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers if you'll encounter such issue later so that the support staff can look into your specific project to see what happens.